# How can I change the root view in a SwiftUI app (no SceneDelegate or AppDelegate)?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm struggling to replace the root view in a pure SwiftUI app. There is no SceneDelegate or AppDelegate. The entry point of the app was originally as follows.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct SampleApp: App {

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainTabView()
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't been able to find any resources that don't leverage the old "delegates". The best I could come up with was to bind to an observable object, but for some reason it's not working.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct SampleApp: App {
    let myController = MyController.shared

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if myController.isUserFullscreen {
                FullScreenView()
            } else {
                MainTabView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your code to update, SwiftUI has to know to look for changes. Most commonly, this is done with an `@ObservableObject` or `@StateObject`. Right now, you just have a regular property called `myController` -- SwiftUI won't know to respond to changes.

You didn't give any information about what MyController is, but I can make some assumptions and turn it into an ObservedObject:

```
class MyController : ObservableObject {
  static let shared = MyController()
  @Published var isUserFullscreen = false
}
```

Then, in your view, you can redefine your property as:

```
@ObservedObject var myController = MyController.shared
```

Then, your view should know to respond to changes on the @Published property of the @ObservableObject.

Here's some more reading on @ObservableObject : https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/observable-objects-environment-objects-and-published

Comment: Ahh thank you! I was conforming `MyController` to `ObservableObject` but I wasn't actually observing it in my view.